# Run Java Tool while processing resources

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project build, where I have a folder containing XML files that are needed as resources in production.
The XML files are part of different build artifacts and should therefore be bundled in their own JAR.

My problem now is that I need 2 different versions of these XML files:

1. the XML files as they are for testing purposes.
2. a stripped down version for production (The stripped down version can be produced by running a JavaExec task)

I want to realize this by specifying a second configuration for the testing purposes producing a `xml-config-test.jar` alongside the `xml-config.jar`.

So, I basically have 2 questions:

1. How can I run the JavaExec task to process the XML files before putting them in the default jar?
2. How can I additionally produce a second test jar *without* processing the XML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the XML files are in a directory `config` under the project directory. You may then create tasks similar to the ones in the following example:

```
def testConfig = fileTree(dir: 'config', include: '**/*.xml')

task testConfigJar(type: Jar) {
    from testConfig
    archiveFileName = 'xml-config-test.jar'
}

task productionConfig(type: JavaExec) {
    def configFiles = testConfig
    inputs.files(configFiles)
    def destinationDir = temporaryDir
    outputs.dir(destinationDir)
    
    classpath = ...
    main = ...
    args = ...
}

task productionConfigJar(type: Jar) {
    from productionConfig
    archiveFileName = 'xml-config.jar'
}
```

Using this skeleton you just need to configure the `productionConfig` task to process the files given by `configFiles` and to store the resulting files inside the directory given by `destinationDir`.

You may then call `gradle testConfigJar` to create the JAR file containing the configuration files for testing and `gradle productionConfigJar` to create the JAR file containing the configuration files for production. You may even bind those tasks to your existing tasks or common lifecycle tasks like `assenble` or `build` (e.g. using `dependsOn`).

Comment: I was somehow misguided that it would be a good idea to add the config folder to the main Java resource source set. But this leads to the problem that per default, the resource are copied into the "main" JAR, which should not contain the original XML files. By simply not using the Java source sets, this is way simpler. Thanks for your input.